# Grails URL mapping gives 404

Tags: grails, url-mapping

This is making me crazy: even though I was sure I have defined this custom mapping correctly, it keeps 404ing.

The resource is nested: a publisher has many channels, a channel belongs to a publisher.

I am trying to make an AJAX call that invokes the getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels function in the Channel controller.

The desired URL format is */publishers/1009303/channels/getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels*

From UrlMappings.groovy:

```
"/publishers"(resources: 'publisher') {
            "/configurations"(resources: "configuration")
            "/metadatas"(resources: "metadata")
            "/xpaths"(resources: "xpath")
            "/channels"(resources: "channel")
            "/crawlrequest"(resources: "crawlRequest")
        }

 "/publishers/${publisherId}/channels/getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels"(controller: "channel", action: "getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels", method: "GET")
```

The UrlMappingsReport shows:

```
Controller: channel
 |   GET    | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels                                       | Action: index                                      |
 |   GET    | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels/create                                | Action: create                                     |
 |   POST   | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels                                       | Action: save                                       |
 |   GET    | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels/${id}                                 | Action: show                                       |
 |   GET    | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels/${id}/edit                            | Action: edit                                       |
 |   PUT    | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels/${id}                                 | Action: update                                     |
 |  PATCH   | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels/${id}                                 | Action: patch                                      |
 |  DELETE  | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels/${id}                                 | Action: delete                                     |
 |   GET    | /publishers/*/channels/getUrlsForChannel                                  | Action: getUrlsForChannel                          |
 |   GET    | /publishers/${publisherId}/channels/getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels      | Action: getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels
```

Moving the custom mapping above or below the general publisher/channel block has no effect.

Even the createLink tag correctly creates the URL:

```
<g:createLink resource="publisher/channel" publisherId="${params.publisherId}" action="getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels" />
```

results in 
https://localhost:8443/publishers/1009303/channels/getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels

The function in the controller is defined as:

*def getMostRecentURLsWithoutChannels(Integer pub) {..}*

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is `Integer pub` mapped in the url?

Comment: That should be `Integer publisherId` as dmahapatro pointed out. (:

Comment: ${publisherID} is the integer in question. While yes it should match, thats not the error I'm getting -- it's a 404 error.

Comment: There are different things that lead to 404.  Does your 404 say that it can't find the view to render?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no it's just 404.